# Trouble connecting to GooglePlayServices on AVD

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I am currently trying to access the GooglePlayServices. The internet for all the other functions on the AVD (API 23) works fine, however I am not quite sure what the problem is on my actual app.

Everytime I try to connect, it says that Connection has failed. I believe I have set up the GoogleAPIClient correctly, though in the ConnectionRequest, I have not customised any of the settings (for simplicity's sake).

This is some of my app's code to provide some information.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name=".Protoype2"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_menu"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.denny.protoype2.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewingWindow"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_viewing_window"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.denny.protoype2.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

onCreate(); from the relevant Class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewing_window);
    mRequestingLocationUpdates = ((Protoype2)getApplication()).getRequestingLocationUpdates();
    if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        StoppedMessage();
    }
    ExceedInstance = 0;
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build();
    String[] LocationPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ViewingWindow.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ViewingWindow.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            GPSExplanation();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ViewingWindow.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

    }
    onRequestPermissionsResult(MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LocationPermission, grantResults);

    final Button BackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.VWBackButton);
    BackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent GoBackIntent = new Intent (ViewingWindow.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(GoBackIntent);
        }
    });
    updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Finally, the several predefined methods of connection:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    createLocationRequest();
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    return new LocationRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your AVD has the appropriate version of the Google Play services APK, implement the [`onConnectionFailed()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener#public-methods) callback method. Use the parameter [`ConnectionResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) that can be used for resolving the error, and deciding what sort of error occurred.

> To resolve the error, the resolution must be started from an activity with a non-negative **requestCode** passed to [`startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#public-methods). Applications should implement onActivityResult in their Activity to call [`connect()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#public-methods) again if the user has resolved the issue (resultCode is [`RESULT_OK`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK)).

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#handle_connection_failures), when your app receives a call to the [`onConnectionFailed()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener#onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult))) callback, you should call [`hasResolution()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#public-methods) on the provided [`ConnectionResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) object. If it returns true, your app can request that the user take immediate action to resolve the error by calling [`startResolutionForResult()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#public-methods) on the [`ConnectionResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) object.

Check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414584/connection-to-google-play-services-failed). Hope it helps!